# Single source, single-ended to differential output low pass filter

Tags: operational-amplifier, signal, differential-amplifier, single-supply-op-amp, signal-conditioning

I want to design an IEPE sensor signal conditioner. This signal conditioner that I will design will not include gain and attenuator parts. The signal from the IEPE sensor will pass through the coupling capacitor and then pass through the low pass filter (gain :1. After filtering the signal, this low pass filter will convert the single-ended signal to a differential output signal and give it to the ADC input.

When I make the configuration in the picture and apply a 10 kHz ±1 V signal, I can get a differential signal with a slight phase shift.

[image]

[image]

---

However, when I put a coupling capacitor at the beginning and add 12 volt DC offset to the AC signal, it does not filter the offset (hp filter with coupling cap) and I get a result like this:

[image]

[image]

I'm having a hard time understanding where my mistake is. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

> *I'm having a hard time understanding where my mistake is. Any idea?*

At the instant the simulation starts it sees a signal and a 12 volt step transient. After some time (milliseconds maybe) this will settle down and the 12 volt transient will subside so, run the simulation for a lot longer and observe the result. Your 2nd graph is impossible to read BTW but, it does show faint signs (over the microsecond time-base) of the outputs rising a little.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Andy, I extended the simulation to 100ms but I don't see any different results.